# When I should use 3rd party uninstallers for Windows?

Tags: uninstall

Are there cases when it is better to use 3rd party uninstallers or I should always use the system one?

Comment: Most 3rd party uninstallers like Revo Uninstaller are either malware or snake oil.  I would never use a program like Revo Uninstaller to remove anything I have installed.  Similar programs like CCleaner, which can also "uninstall" programs, are only helpful because of their other features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using third-party uninstallers: The ones that came with the software when you installed them. There is no system uninstaller.

The closest thing to that is Windows Installer, but it’s really just a runtime for install packages – which are, of course, provided by third parties.

Software like Revo Uninstaller is completely unnecessary in most cases. They claim to “Delete leftover data after regular uninstall” among other similarly *fantastic* features. It’s really like TuneUp 97 all over again.

The only thing that *is* possible is auditing the *installation* process to create a complete list of things that were changed. These changes can then be reverted.